# Making Music Notes in Python

Tags: python

I've got a project to make a sort of music synthesizer with python3. I've got to use numbers from stock data and create a player file and a file with my music class that will output notes to a .rra file with my play function.

m.play(D,3,2) Playing a D in the third octave for 2 beats.

I'm still really confused how my play function would work. To play a certain note at an octave I assume I would append the stock data numbers for as long as the note is supposed to play. I'm confused as how I would input this into code.

## Any help or tips at all would be appreciated.

Here is the skeleton for my music class file and my player file:

I would play it with the command: "python3 player.py stock.dat | aplay"

### music.py

class music:

```
def __init__(self, infile):

    self.infile = infile
    self.beats = 4
    self.list = []
    fp = open(infile, 'r')
    for line in fp:
        self.list.append(eval(line))
    pass

def set_beat(self, x):
    self.beats = x

def header(self):
    print("RRA\n%%\n")

def play(self, note, octave, beats):
    pass

def __str__(self):
    s = "infile" + self.infile + ", Beats:" + self.beats
```

---

### player.py

```
import sys
from music import Music

def main():

m = Music(sys.argv[1])

m.set_beat(0.25) # one beat is 0.25 seconds

m.header() #output the audio header

m.play("C",3,1) # play C in octave 3 for one beat

m.play("D",3,2) # play D in octave 3 for two beats

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The command: "python3 player.py stock.dat | aplay" indicates that you wish to stream a file to the aplay utility, the audio player for an ALSA sound card driver. Without any options, the input defaults to U8 format.

[aplay man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay)

I can't find any details on the format of such a file, but that is where you should start. If you are allowed to choose some options for aplay (by adding -options to the end of the command line), then you can maybe find an easier format to use.

The basic idea for your project is to take a sort of "MIDI" format that your instructor has no doubt specified, in which notes and beats, etc. are given, and output the raw sound file in a standard format. You should notice that the Midi-like compressed format is a much smaller file.

Answer (score 0):

Why the RRA format?

I have worked on something similar but used mostly the MIDI format internally.

A sample program which plays a midi file is [here](https://github.com/albertz/learn-midi/blob/master/playmidi.py). In the function `midievents_to_rawpcm` (defined [here](https://github.com/albertz/learn-midi/blob/master/decode.py)), I am using fluidsynth for synthesizing.

A sample program which takes keyboard input and interprets them as piano keys is [here](https://github.com/albertz/learn-midi/blob/master/keyboard-player.py).